# Are the following sentences parallel?

Tags: parallelism

Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but also the band was late.

Not only will they paint the outside of the house but also the inside.

Comment: They both contain "Not only...but also...", so yes, together, they are. However, it's difficult to see them as a real-world example of parallelism.

Comment: They certainly don't have exactly the same form. Contrast 'Oily old rags burn fiercely' and  'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously'. _And I'd reposition 'not only' in the second sentence, to [after 'paint' and] before 'the outside ...'._

Answer (score 1):

They are parallel in that there is a coordination in both with *but* and modifier *not only* present at the start of the sentence, but the coordination is not of like categories. In the first there is a coordination of clauses, and in the second of noun phrases.

> [Not only was it raining all day at the wedding] [but [also the band was late.]]
>
> Not only will they paint [the outside of the house] [but [also the inside.]]

Comment: The structure of the second is shown more clearly by a more logical (if probably less idiomatic) re-ordering: They will paint _not only_ {the outside of the house} _but also_ {the inside [of the house]}.